# Кнопки клоны в Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Здравствуйте.  Хотел бы узнать, вроде как глупо, допустим у приложения делать, две кнопки с одинаковыми функциями, но с разным названием. Например как: "курсив" и "наклонный"...  Но почему-то корпорация MS, так наверное не считает и сделала такие кнопки...  В `"персонализации" > "Экран"`  Это: "Настройка разрешения экрана" и "Настройка параметров экрана".  См. скрин:  ![alt text][1] Объясните мне, как программисту, в чём их функциональное отличие? И для чего такая необходимость?  P.S. Может уже чего-то не понимаю и мне надо переучиваться, ведь начинал с win98?[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXx2d.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Ничем) по крайне мере судя по результату) может чтото "обратной совместимости" в отношении пользователя :)

Comment: "обратная совместимость" в отношении пользователя :)А это что такое ? :) Совместимость понимаю... а обратная совместимость, как это?Вот например прогресс, а обратное прогрессу - это регресс.Так есть тогда название этому - "обратная совместимость"? ;)

Comment: Обратная совместимость, это значит, что допустим, диск SATAIII всегда будет работать на контроллере SATAII, т.к. протоколы обратно совместимы.  Если вы являетесь программистом, то, у вас есть уже опыт, и, наверное, не раз уже замечали нелогичности в ПО от мелкомягких. Этот вопрос нужно адресовать БольшомуБиллу и его программерам

Comment: ну я криво выразился, но имел ввиду, что новая система -- новое название, но "почемуто" решили добавить и старое название... эт просто к примеру))) ну кто их знает) может багофича какаято...

Comment: to: Justicet  По железу и софту объяснять не стоило, стаж 13 лет, это было и так известно.  WinХР понимала и FAT32, и новую для дом.ОСей NTFS, "понимание" "старой" FAT32 и есть обратная совместимость. Но тут-то я привел именно КНОПКИ(или точнее ссылки) и их 2(!) и они ведут юзера в одно место (я хотел сказать в место смены разрешения экрана монитора)  Одним словом понятно, что одним багом, даже не багом, а рудиментом в Винде стало больше.